# AsyncStorage with ListView react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Hi i want to make a screen with a list where i can show what the user saved as favourite. I use local json file to keep the orginal data. and from there i want to save the favourite data on AsyncStorage. the AsyncStorage returns a promise and i can't add it on the state. How can i do it?

```
const  ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
let a
export default class List extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    let resultData = new Array;
    super(props)
    const dataPoem =  AsyncStorage.getItem('PoemDB', (err, result) => {
        a = JSON.parse(result)
        return result

    });

    console.log
   this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(dataPoem),
      counter: 1,
      fontLoaded: false,
    };

  }
```

Comment: I would recommend that you post your code here, add in a few ways you have tried to solve the problem and the outcome of those attempts.

Comment: I followed you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, `AsyncStorage.getItem` returns a **promise**, so you must deal with it as a promise.
You need to rely on the response from `AsyncStorage.getItem()` so that you may be sure it is handled. You can deal with this using `then`. Once the promise is returned, state will be set asynchronously:

```
var dataPoem = function(){
  AsyncStorage.getItem('PoemDB').then((data) => {
       this.setState({
         dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
       });
  });
}
```

Or you can deal with a promise using `await`, a concept that came with es7.
An example from the docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html):

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
  if (value !== null){
    // We have data!!
    console.log(value);
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

Or, you could create your own promise, and return a promise using `resolve`:

```
var getFavouriteData = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  AsyncStorage.getitem().then((data) => {
    resolve(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: this return promises. I get `
{"_45":0,"_81":0,"_65":null,"_54":null}` how can i handle this promises in this case?

Comment: I had the same problem recently! I will be back in a few hours to help, in class.

Comment: I would try the first solution, using then, and I would put it inside of the constructor. I am confident it will work.

Comment: Yes! first solution works but i have to use `async componentWillMount() ` and inside `await AsyncStorage.getItem('PoemDB').then((data) => {}`
again i make a conditional state like if dataloaded then render the component!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make a conditional state with this

```
    constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds
    }

  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
      if (value !== null) {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(JSON.parse(value))
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data
    }

  }
```

**Render**

```
render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(data) => this.renderRow(data)}
      />
    );
  }



renderRow = (data) => {
    return (
     console.log(data);
      <View>
        <Text>.....<Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Hope this will help others!